# how do I Check deleted Account with Telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I send telegram message with Telegram bot to a big List of chatID
how can I find the deleted Account ID Before Sending Message to ChatID lists

I don't want to Send message to Deleted Accounts, how to find them

i using Telegram.Bot that Created by [Mr.RoundRobin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant found out deleted accounts or blocked users without sending them message.